# datasource must not be null in spring batch jdbccursoritemreader

Tags: spring

I am trying to pass a hashmap from one step to another step and use the map to create query and execute in next step. I am getting datasource must not be null while doing same.

Below is my code where I am trying to retrieve value and run query. I would have not retrieved and dynamically passed it yet. But I will be replacing this query dynamically.

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception{

    JobExecution jobExecution         = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
    ExecutionContext jobContext     = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<HashMap<String,String>> mapList = (List<HashMap<String, String>>) jobContext.get("mapList");
    System.out.println("size of map received:::::::"+ mapList.size());

    setSql("select count(*) as countValue from table where id=578");
    setRowMapper(new dbMapper());
    setDataSource(dataSource);
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
}   

@BeforeStep
public void saveStepExecution(final StepExecution stepExecution) {

    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;

}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to add one yet. Does the class that this sample is from already have a setter for dataSource? If so, you need to change `setDataSource(dataSource);` to `super.setDataSource(dataSource);`.